# Namespace-like access in class

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

For a container class I'd like to provide an interface with several functions which are *grouped* into categories, for example:

```c++
Data::Get::FirstGetter()   
Data::Get::SecondGetter()  
Data::Set::FirstSetter()  
Data::Set::FirstSetter()
```

This would allow for something like this:

```
Data myData;
myData::Set::FirstSetter( stuff );
std::cout << myData::Get::FirstGetter() << std::endl; // -> "stuff"
```

Obviously the code itself is bogus and I've used the scope operator `::` as a potential placeholder for something else (I am aware that you can not create namespaces within a class).

An approach to achieve something like this is demonstrated in the following snippet:

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
private:
    struct aBar {
        void IFunc(){
            std::cout << "IFunc()" << std::endl;
        }
    };
public:
    void OFunc(){
    std::cout << "OFunc()" << std::endl;
    }
    aBar Bar;
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.OFunc();
    foo.Bar.IFunc();
}
```

However, in order to use this, one must create an instance of each *grouping object* (in the pseudocode example one instance of `Get` and another one of `Set`, in the dummy example one instance of `aBar`). Is there a way to achieve this functionality in a different way (maybe using the actual scope operator `::` to indicate the member that is to be called resides within an inner scope)?

Comment: It is possible, but why would you want t do that instead of just wirte direkt methods?

Comment: Static functions/members

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to circumvent "normal" members? Or what would be the actual use case you're trying to achieve, in contrast to `Data.m_get.firstGetter()` / `Data.m_get.secondGetter()`, where `m_get` is some member class?

Comment: Yes of course, one can do the very same thing using a `Get`/`Set` member class (as I illustrated above). I'm just asking whether there's another way to achieve this which would indeed circumvent **creating** an instance of the `Get`/`Set` inner class.

Comment: I think you should rethink your design. There is no elegant way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the reason why you want to achieve such a behaviour. However, if you want to achieve something like that you may get inspired by the following (although I won't ever use some code like this in any project, still not seeing one plausible reason):

```
#include <iostream>

class Interface1
{
protected:
  virtual ~Interface1() {}
  virtual void DoStuff1() = 0;
};

class Interface2
{
protected:
  virtual ~Interface2() {}
  virtual void DoStuff2() = 0;
};

class Interface3
{
protected:
  virtual ~Interface3() {}
  virtual void DoStuff3() = 0;
};

class Container;

class Grouper1
{
public:
  static void DoStuff1(Container& arContainer);
  static void DoStuff2(Container& arContainer);
};

class Grouper2
{
public:
  static void DoStuff3(Container& arContainer);
};

class Container : public Interface1, public Interface2, public Interface3
{
public:
  virtual ~Container() {}
private:
  friend class Grouper1;
  friend class Grouper2;
  virtual void DoStuff1() { printf("DoStuff1()\n"); }
  virtual void DoStuff2() { printf("DoStuff2()\n"); }
  virtual void DoStuff3() { printf("DoStuff3()\n"); }
};

void Grouper1::DoStuff1(Container& arContainer) { arContainer.DoStuff1(); }
void Grouper1::DoStuff2(Container& arContainer) { arContainer.DoStuff2(); }

void Grouper2::DoStuff3(Container& arContainer) { arContainer.DoStuff3(); }

int main(int aArgc, char** aArgv)
{
  Container c;
  Grouper1::DoStuff1(c);
  Grouper1::DoStuff2(c);
  Grouper2::DoStuff3(c);
  return 0;
}
```

This way your Container can implement some interfaces and your Groupers provide static functions (grouped) to access those methods (although you need to pass the actual Container, you want to work on). But definitely you won't achieve namespace-like access if you don't provide some helper functions/classes (as Grouper1, Grouper2).